# How can I change the "App_Themes" directory in ASP.Net?

Tags: .net, asp.net, configuration, web-config, themes

I'm upgrading a .Net application from .net 1.1 to 3.5. All the themes are stored in a folder called `Themes`, the new .Net 3.5 framework wants this information in a folder called `App_Themes`. It will be a major refactoring for me to move everything to a `App_Themes` folder.

So I want to ask if there is a way to tell .Net what folder to use when looking for themes? How can I change the default directory from `App_Themes` to `Themes`?

Comment: Why would be a major refactoring?

Comment: @Claudio Before .Net introduced managed themes with the App_Themes folder, this code had developed a solution using the Themes folder. There are hundreds of references to that directory. I tried a global find and replace, but was still getting errors. This is why I wanted to just try changing the location .Net is looking.

Comment: and the error is that it can't find the theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My memory is a bit foggy, but I don't seem to recall .NET 1.1 having the theming support which got built into 2.0 in the "App_Themes" folder. So I think you can just leave things in your themes folder and keep using whatever existing home-rolled theme plumbing you've got and transition to using the native 2.0+ theming if you want/need to.

Comment: We basically are going to disable ASP.Net themes and use the homegrown approach. Thanks for the feedback.